# Couchbase can't MutateIn multiple upserts with null value

Tags: c#, .net-core, couchbase

I have a Couchbase document that I want to mutate multiple properties on in one call. If one of the property values is null, the mutate fails with a message of:

> KV Error: {Name="EINVAL", Description="Invalid packet", Attributes="internal,invalid-input"}

and a status of

> Couchbase.IO.ResponseStatus.InvalidArguments

If I just try to mutate a single property with null, and if none of the property values are null. The mutate will be successful.

Also if I try to mutate multiple properties to null it will fail.

```cs
// This works
var mutatedWorks1 = bucket.MutateIn<dynamic>(doc1.DocId)
    .Upsert("nullProperty", "NotNull")
    .Upsert("name", "MutatedName")
    .Execute();

// This also works
var mutatedWorks2 = bucket.MutateIn<dynamic>(doc1.DocId)
    .Upsert("nullProperty", null)
    .Execute();

// This doesn't work
var mutatedNotWork = bucket.MutateIn<dynamic>(doc1.DocId)
    .Upsert("nullProperty", null)
    .Upsert("name", "MutatedName")
    .Execute();      

// This also doesn't work
var mutatedNotWork = bucket.MutateIn<dynamic>(doc1.DocId)
    .Upsert("nullProperty", null)
    .Upsert("name", null)
    .Execute();
```

Couchbase client is .Net SDK 2.7.10

How can I mutate multiple properties if one or more of the property values are null?

Comment: Now getting this issue with SDK v 3.0.6. Looks like they re introduced a bug lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has now been fixed ([NCBC-2038](https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/NCBC-2038)) and is scheduled for release in our next maintenance patch which is scheduled for 6th Aug 2019.

Thanks