# Couchbase Server KV Error: "EINVAL" on null Upsert

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, couchbase

I have a Couchbase document that I want to mutate using server version 6.6.0, CouchbaseNetClient 3.0.5, Couchbase.Extensions.DependencyInjection 3.0.4.811.

Document:

```
{
    "name": "First Last",
    "email": null
}
```

Mutate Code:

```
var bucket = await _bucketProvider.GetBucketAsync();
await bucket.DefaultCollection().MutateInAsync(updatedProfile.Id, new[]
{
    MutateInSpec.Upsert("name", updatedProfile.Name),
    MutateInSpec.Upsert("email", updatedProfile.Email)
});
```

When the new email value is null I get the following error:

> KV Error: {Name="EINVAL", Description="Invalid packet",
> Attributes="internal,invalid-input"}

This appears to be a bug and unfortunately I can't submit an issue to the .NET client's repository on GitHub.

I found a similar post here [Couchbase can't MutateIn multiple upserts with null value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57116620/couchbase-cant-mutatein-multiple-upserts-with-null-value)
, but even if I update only one value it still won't mutate to null.

Any help will be appreciated.

**NOTE:** Following is a sample snippet, which reproduces the issue.

```
class Program
{
    private static ICluster _cluster;

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var userInfo = new
        {
            Name = "User1",
            Email = (string)null // *** This is causing the exception. ***
        };

        _cluster = await Cluster.ConnectAsync("couchbase://localhost", "Administrator", "Password");

        var bucket = await _cluster.BucketAsync("items");
        await bucket.DefaultCollection().MutateInAsync("doc1", new[]
        {
            MutateInSpec.Upsert("name", userInfo.Name),
            MutateInSpec.Upsert("email", userInfo.Email) // *** Setting the null value ***
        });

        _cluster.Dispose();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Couchbase Jira Issue - https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/NCBC-2640

Comment: You can file bugs at https://issues.couchbase.com/

Comment: Thank for the link - I registered and created an issue - https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/NCBC-2640

Comment: For whoever has this same issue with Go, I just opened another ticket specific to the Go SDK: https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/GOCBC-994

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been identified by the Couchbase team as a bug. You can follow the progress here - https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/NCBC-2640

Answer (score 2):

Update: This appears to be a bug - https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/NCBC-2640

---

I just tried this with the latest version of the .NET SDK ([3.0.5, just released today](https://docs.couchbase.com/dotnet-sdk/3.0/project-docs/sdk-release-notes.html#version-3-0-5-1-september-2020)) and it works, no error. I first created your example document manually. Then I ran this in a console app:

```
class Program
{
    private static ICluster _cluster;

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
         _cluster = await Cluster.ConnectAsync("couchbase://localhost", "Administrator", "password");

        var bucket = await _cluster.BucketAsync("bucket");
        var result = await bucket.DefaultCollection().MutateInAsync("doc1", new[]
        {
            MutateInSpec.Upsert("name", "new name"),
            MutateInSpec.Upsert("email", "new email") // this works fine, but `default(string)` instead of "new email" causes an exception
        });

        _cluster.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Without knowing what version of the SDK you're using, I'd speculate that this is a bug that has been fixed.

Another possibility: I noticed the use of `_bucketProvider`. The `Couchbase.Extensions.DependencyInjection` library might be using an older version of the SDK by default, so remember that you can add/update both libraries individually with NuGet. (Again, just speculating about what versions you might be using).

Comment: Thank you for looking into this! I made a new app only with the .NET client 3.0.5 and ran your code. I only made a small modification to set "email" to null instead of "new email" and the issue appears.

Comment: I understand! I will try it again.

Comment: You are right, it's definitely a bug. I was able to reproduce; I added a stack track and log output to your ticket. Thank you for opening it!